# My app always crashes everytime I click friends fragment,allusers activity and settings activity referring to same error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

The following is the code:

```
package com.example.convo;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.NetworkPolicy;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView myFriensList;

    private DatabaseReference FriendsReference;
    private DatabaseReference UsersReference;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    String online_user_id;

    private View myMainView;

    public FriendsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        myMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);


        myFriensList = myMainView.findViewById(R.id.friends_list);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        online_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        FriendsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(online_user_id);
        FriendsReference.keepSynced(true);
        UsersReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        UsersReference.keepSynced(true);

        myFriensList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return myMainView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
                = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder>
                (
                        Friends.class,
                        R.layout.all_users_display_layout,
                        FriendsViewHolder.class,
                        FriendsReference
                ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final FriendsViewHolder viewHolder, Friends model,final int position) {
                viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());

                final String list_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                /*
                    viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            String visit_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(AllUsersActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                            profileIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", visit_user_id);
                            startActivity(profileIntent);
                        }
                    });
                */

                UsersReference.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("user_name").getValue().toString();
                        String thumbImage = dataSnapshot.child("user_thumb_image").getValue().toString();

                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("online")){
                            String online_status = (String) dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();

                            viewHolder.setUserOnline(online_status);
                        }

                        viewHolder.setUserName(userName);
                        viewHolder.setThumbImage(thumbImage, getContext());

                        viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]
                                {
                                    userName + "'s Profile",
                                    "Send Message"
                                };

                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                                builder.setTitle("Select Options");

                                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                                        if(position == 0){
                                            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                                            profileIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", list_user_id);
                                            startActivity(profileIntent);
                                        }

                                        if(position == 1){
                                            if(dataSnapshot.child("online").exists()){
                                                Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                                                chatIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", list_user_id);
                                                chatIntent.putExtra("user_name", userName);
                                                startActivity(chatIntent);
                                            }

                                            else {
                                                UsersReference.child(list_user_id).child("online")
                                                              .setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                        Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                                                        chatIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", list_user_id);
                                                        chatIntent.putExtra("user_name", userName);
                                                        startActivity(chatIntent);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                builder.show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        };

        myFriensList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }


    public static class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView;

        public FriendsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setDate(String date){
            TextView sinceFriendsDate = mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_status);
            sinceFriendsDate.setText(date);
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName){
            TextView userNameDisplay = mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_username);
            userNameDisplay.setText(userName);
        }

        public void setThumbImage(final String thumbImage, final Context applkicationContext) {
            final CircleImageView image = mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_profile_image);

            // Loading images offline
            Picasso.get().load(thumbImage).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile)
                   .into(image, new Callback() {
                       @Override
                       public void onSuccess() {

                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onError(Exception e) {
                           Picasso.get().load(thumbImage).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile).into(image);

                       }
                   });
        }

        public void setUserOnline(String online_status) {
            ImageView onlineStatusView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.online_status);

            if(online_status.equals(true)){
                onlineStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            else {
                onlineStatusView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below are the error logs:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.koekoe.convo, PID: 15381
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
>                         at com.koekoe.convo.FriendsFragment$1$1.onDataChange(FriendsFragment.java:115)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source:13)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZT(Unknown Source:2)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source:69)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15381 SIG: 9
>   Application terminated.

Comment: One of your getValue is returning null

Comment: Put the debugger over                     final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("user_name").getValue().toString();
 and see if this null similarly repeat for such values, you would find the one which is null, fix that, it will work

Comment: i do not understand, how do i go about that debugger?

Comment: @Kopi This is not how you edit a post . If you editing a post try to make it right in single edit .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

dataSnapshot.child doesn't have child "user_name"

About that:

```
I do not understand, how do I go about that debugger
```

Here it is pretty well explained:
*[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)*

And for now I give a little tip read about breakpoints. At first put it in a place where you are getting the error and in the debugger window check values which is null, and then write it here.

Maybe we will help.

And correct you question.